# run c++ program in linux terminal with command

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

I have a cpp file called FileSystem.cpp, while I want to use the linux terminal and call the FileSystem executable file with command

> FileSystem -i

" no matter where it located and call it without extension or './' at the front. I tried call it directly from terminal but it said:

```
FileSystem: command not found
```

Comment: did you compile your `.cpp` file?
`g++ FileSystem.cpp -o FileSystem` then run `./FileSystem`

Comment: Have you compiled your `FileSystem.cpp` into an executable? Is it called `FileSystem` (e.g. you compiled it with `g++ -o FileSystem FileSystem.cpp`).

Comment: Programming with C++ is a four-step process: Edit source; Compile source into object files; Link object files into executable; And run executable. Iterate as needed. You seem to be missing most of the steps.

Comment: A better compilation command would be `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g  FileSystem.cpp -o FileSystem` because you want all warnings and debug info from [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Answer (score 0):

When you type a command into the command line like `FileSystem -i`, without an explicit path on the command (no `/` characters in the first word), it looks for the exectuable in your `$PATH`.  You can use the command `echo $PATH` to see what your current path is.

Normally, on linux, your path will include the directory `$HOME/bin` if it exists.  That's the `bin` directory in your home directory, so you can put an executable you create (such as `FileSystem`) in that directory and then run it as `FileSystem -i`

Comment: It is not normally on Linux, but normally on Ubuntu, that `$HOME/bin` is in `$PATH`

Comment: And if it's not in your `$PATH` on your distro, edit `.bashrc` to add `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"`

Comment: i have add my path with " export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin" and when I use echo $PATH i can see my path is there, but still it couldn't recognize the FileSystem command